# Java Spring: How to send http request to https urls?

Tags: java, spring, rest, ssl, https

I have to send GET request to some API without any parameters so I wrote the code:

```
public Boolean getData(String apiUrl) {

        try {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(apiUrl, String.class);

            if (responseEntity.getStatusCode().toString().equals("200")) {
                theLogger.info("Server successfully answered with response code: {} - {}", responseEntity.getStatusCode().toString(), responseEntity.getBody());
                return true;
            } else {
                theLogger.error("Something goes wrong! Server answered with response code: {} and error: {}", responseEntity.getStatusCode().toString(), responseEntity.getBody());
                return false;
            }

        } catch (Exception theException) {
            theException.printStackTrace();
            theLogger.error("Cannot send channelInfo! Exception: " + theException);
            return false;
        }

}
```

It works when API url is HTTP, but doesn't work with HTTPS. It says:

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I believe it's because my code doesn't trust this certificate. But I don't know what should I do with it? The API is public and it opens in any web-browser it is just some https site. I couldn't believe that I should download certificates for all https sites which I work with and add this certificates somewhere. I believe that it should be the more common way to trust this public sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://mariuszprzydatek.com/2013/07/19/disabling-ssl-certificate-validation/)
So if have to deal with certificate which was issued by not trusted CA, but in your case, you don't really care about trust. You can disable SSL certificate validation by code:

```
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class SSLCertificateValidation {

    public static void disable() {
        try {
            SSLContext sslc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            TrustManager[] trustManagerArray = { new NullX509TrustManager() };
            sslc.init(null, trustManagerArray, null);
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslc.getSocketFactory());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new NullHostnameVerifier());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static class NullX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            System.out.println();
        }
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            System.out.println();
        }
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new X509Certificate[0];
        }
    }

    private static class NullHostnameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Invoke SSLCertificateValidation.disable() prior to making a HTTPS call.